# iPad Tab Bar React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a problem only in the iPad mini 2 I am getting the tab bar of my app generated by react navigation (icon + label) in row instead of column. In the other devices iPhones and iPad Pro, Android, I get the icon and the label in column. 
Do you know any possible problem that could be causing this

Comment: I’ve noticed it too.

Comment: I solved adding this in the createBottomTabBar,  tabBarOptions: {
          ...
            tabStyle: {
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'space-around'
            },
        }

Comment: Write it up and answer your own question

Answer (score 8):

The best solution is to specify the labelPosition in tab bar options
tabBarOptions={{
labelPosition: "below-icon"
}}>

Comment: It's should be the accepted answer, thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding this in the tab bar navigation

```
 createBottomTabBar({
   tabBarOptions: { 

   ... 
      tabStyle: { 
        flexDirection: 'column', 
        alignItems: 'center', 
        justifyContent: 'space-around' }, 
      }
 })
```